# How get just some elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, template-matching

(Sorry my bad english)
I'm making an program write on python using OpenCv and another minor libraries, basically my program need to find an image on my screen based on an Template. I used the Template Matching to this. The program identifies the template on screen and send the right left pixel as an array to the output. But, there some numbers that i dont want, i just want grab the first 3 numbers of the array.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

while True:
    #Template Matching of the block
    img_rgb = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(448, 168, 1471, 935))
    img_rgb = np.asarray(img_rgb)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.imread("Templates/rock.jpg",0)
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 
    threshold = 0.9
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

    #Template Matching of the Character
    templatec = cv2.imread("Templates/char.jpg",0)
    wc, hc = templatec.shape[::-1]

    resc = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,templatec,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    thresholdc = 0.6
    locc = np.where( resc >= thresholdc)
    for pt in zip(*locc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,0), 2)

    cv2.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
    print(locc)
```

The output with the object in my screen is: (array([367, 368, 368, 368, 369], dtype=int32), array([490, 489, 490, 491, 490], dtype=int32)).

But i just want the "367" of the first array, and the "490" of the second

Comment: What do you get from `print(type(locc))`? As posted, it looks like a tuple but I don't know if that is a quirk of how it's displayed.

Comment: If it is a tuple, `result = [item[0] for item in locc]`

Comment: If I use locc[0] it will return this: [367, 368, 368, 368, 369], but I only want the 367 of this part.

Comment: a) that doesn't address my first question and b) I guessed your issue and answered correctly in my second comment in that case. Rather than re-state the problem, could you perhaps read and take on-board the feedback you have been given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a one-dimensional Numpy array and just want to grab part of it, then you can use the "**:**" operator the same way you can with a Python list.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array((1,2,3,4))
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[0:2]
array([1, 2])
>>> a[1:2]
array([2])
>>> print(a[:3])
[1 2 3]
>>> b = a[0:3]
>>> print(b)
[1 2 3]
>>> type(b)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> print(a[0])
1
>>> type(a[0])
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

**EDIT:** If `locc[0]` gives you back [367, 368, 368, 368, 369] and you only want 367, then try `loc[0][0]`.  If you want [367] so you can still treat the data as a list, try `[loc[0][0]]`.

Comment: I'm really confused how this pertains to the OP's question

Comment: The OP said he has some numpy arrays and only wants to grab part of them.

Comment: They (apprear to be) are arrays in a tuple. That makes all of the slicing demos irrelevant here, and they are covered in great detail in other posts and resources. The OP has not got back to me on my questions for clarification.

Comment: If I use locc[0] it will return this: [367, 368, 368, 368, 369], but I only want the 367 of this part.

Comment: What does locc[0][0] give you?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, when I used locc[0][0] the output was only 367, thank you soo much!

Comment: You're welcome!  If you still need that in a list, albeit a list of just one element, you could use [loc[0][0]].

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first element of the array with `locc[0]`.

(I am assuming that the two array objects you've posted are from two cycles of the `while` loop, so each iteration of `locc` is a 1D array.)

Comment: If I use locc[0] it will return this: [367, 368, 368, 368, 369], but I only want the 367 of this part.

Comment: You can get the first element of *that* array by appending `[0]`, i.e. `locc[0][0]`.